# A second past-form: "dig" / "digged" / "digged"

Tags: slang, past-tense, irregular-verbs

I've been digging through the Internet and I can't find any legit answers to this question, even in English dictionaries. Probably because this particular usage is rarely used in the past tense.

> She's playing hard to get, but I'm sure she digs me!

While this usage is quite normal, what if I wanted to use the verb *dig* in the past tense?

> She digged me and I hadn't even noticed it!

OR

> She dug me and I hadn't even noticed it!

Which form will be used? The former? The later? Both? While the second one is Standard English, and I'm sure it's perfectly acceptable, would the first one be acceptable in speech? Or would it strike a native speaker as quite odd?

Comment: It's slang, and slang doesn't obey official rules. You'll have to find out what gets used by people who are cool enough to use  _dig_ in this sense. Which is not us fuddy-duddy grammarians.

Comment: @JohnLawler Be that as it may, I could nonetheless discover no instances of *really digged* for *really dug*.

Comment: There you go. Norma Loquendi has spoken.

Comment: The slang use of "dig" has been around since the 50s, at least, and is well-established.  To my recollection, the past tense of the slang version has always been "dug", except then the speaker was ostensibly illiterate.

Comment: May I ask why you are using past perfect...had noticed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In present-day English, both the past tense and the past participle of the verb *dig* are *dug*. The OED says:

> *Dig* cannot be derived from, or in any way directly related to, OE. *díc* dike, ditch, and *dícian* to dike, embank, from which it differs both in vowel and final consonant; but if the French derivation be correct, it goes back through Fr. to the same Teutonic root. It is properly a weak verb, pa. t. and pple. *digged*, but in 16th c. received a strong pa. pple. *dug*, analogous to *stuck*, which since 18th c. has also been used as pa. t.

If you said *digged* today in lieu of *dug*, it would sound not archaic but so completely obsolete as to be wrong. See [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=digged%2Cdug&year_start=1550&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdigged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdug%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram of digged versus dug]

A  hundredfold difference cannot be overcome: it will sound wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The slang sense of *dig* is quoted in the OED - (meaning 6c.)

One example of its use is in the past tense - which has been taken to be ***dug***.

> 1959   C. MacInnes Absolute Beginners 62   Everything you learned, you
>   hadn't learned until you'd really dug it: i.e., made it part of your
>   own experience.

Surprisingly there were examples of the slang sense dating from 1935. I had always assumed it began in the 1950s. The entries do however confirm that it is now dated, the last example being for 1969.